# is fields_view_get() called when creating record

Tags: methods, odoo

The question might be silly.

I am not sure about this. Is fields_view_get() executed on create?

In my case i have created fields_view_get() in res_partner(account/partner). When I load page and create customer fields_view_get() executed but after that when I create any record(Form View) it doesn't get called. If I reload page and create customer(Form View) method(fields_view_get) gets call for first create.

Is it default behavior?

Answer (score 4):

fields_view_get() is called whenever tree or form is opened. It doesnt depends on create or write functions. What view you defined in xml for the model will be loaded by default.

Comment: Thanx for quick reply and Yes i read it but i didn't get this logic fully :( when first time i create a record fields_view_get() executed but 2nd time it doesn't.

Comment: When you are opening the view(tree/form), fields_view_get() is executed and view is loaded. then creating a new record or updating an existing  record will use this loaded view. If you want to load it again you need to refresh.